# Alternative to Tex FoG

Tags: syntax-checker

I use an app for Mac OSX called TexFoG which gives me an assortment of common syntaxes for LaTex, this version is 1.3 and is a 32 bit version that will soon be obsolete. dose anyone know of an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We are not a community about alternatives of TeX and friends but about real TeX (and real friends :P) ... So, my answer would be to try the original TeX of texlive (or a friend like MacTeX for your mac)

Comment: @koleygr from a quick search this is an _editor_ with a graphical pallet for choosing fractions and matrix layouts etc, it just writes source then you need a tex distribution, so I think it is on topic here (although I can not help the OP with any suggestions)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ... Then may be `LyX` could be an option .... Thanks for informing!

Comment: In TeXShop, the menu items Window > LaTeX Panel and Window > Matrix Panel give you some of the functionality of FofG, but far from all. I suggest you post to the TeX on Mac OS X Mailing List (Mac macosx-tex@email.esm.psu.edu) asking for an addition of another TeXShop panel that would fill the gap.

Comment: TeXStudio also has buttons for common syntax, see for example the screenshot in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5281/. Also for Mac.